# For a large array (16,000+ rows): How to find index value of a 2D array that satisfies a certain condition, as quickly as possible?

Tags: python, arrays, large-files

I have a dataset having x coordinates, y coordinates, and a function value. I have a function that checks for input coordinates, and does something whether or not the value is found. But for the large sized numpy array,it takes too long, a second to check through two such arrays (x and y).

The reason it is a 'long time' is because this same checking happens few thousand times itself. Basically, I am tring to match the function value from one large grid with its own spacing in x and y to a new large grid with different spacing, using interpolation when the x, y values do not match.

Is there a faster way to find the proper index? The problem is, the new grid values cannot be assigned for all grid points at the same time like using a text file, its coordinates get passed one at a time using a function (rules of an open source library). Moreover, the read_excel() needs to be called several times too, since this function can only handle the new grid coordinates as its arguments, otherwise there are constructor errors that calls this function.

I tried this common way:

```
def assign_to_new_grid(p):
    old_grid_values_pd = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    old_grid_values = np.array(old_grid_values_pd)
    if p.x in old_grid_values[:,0] and p.y in old_grid_values[:,1]:
        #Assign simply, 0th column has x values, 1st column has y values
    else:
        #Interpolate
```

This gets called for all thousands of points in the new grid. There's no way to use a list of the new coordinates productively, since that will only eliminate the need for the else statement, not the function as a whole.

Comment: Quickfix: don't use Python. Use numpy or something that uses C++ under the hoods

Comment: @ThomasWeller It is indeed a numpy array on which the value check occurs.

Comment: Your problem is complex, and I think I did not understood everything you tried to explain.
But when looking at performance problems, there is a golden rule : measure the total time, and the time for each part, to know if and where to put your efforts. But your case does not look easy to monitor though.

Comment: @Lenormju Yeah, it seems like an impassable bottleneck that can only be resolved by better hardware or the library devs adding better support for large datasets.

Answer (score 0):

If one of your performance problems is reading the file countless time, like that :

```py
read_excel_count = 0
def pd_read_excel(filename):  # fake for demo
    global read_excel_count
    read_excel_count += 1
    print(f"call pd_read_excel, {filename=!r}, {read_excel_count=}")


def assign_to_new_grid(p):
    old_grid_values_pd = pd_read_excel('data.xlsx')
    # ...


for i in range(100):
    assign_to_new_grid(...)
```

```
call pd_read_excel, filename='data.xlsx', read_excel_count=1
call pd_read_excel, filename='data.xlsx', read_excel_count=2
call pd_read_excel, filename='data.xlsx', read_excel_count=3
...
call pd_read_excel, filename='data.xlsx', read_excel_count=99
call pd_read_excel, filename='data.xlsx', read_excel_count=100
```

Then you can read it once and reuse it afterwards, by creating a class to store the data, and giving a method instead of a function to your framework, like so :

```py
read_excel_count = 0  # reset

class Something:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = pd_read_excel(filename)

    def assign_to_new_grid(self, p):
        old_grid_values_pd = self.data
        # ...

filename = 'data.xlsx'
assign_to_new_grid = Something(filename).assign_to_new_grid  # taking a reference on the instance's method

for i in range(100):
    assign_to_new_grid(...)
```

Which will result in only 1 call :

```
call pd_read_excel, filename='data.xlsx', read_excel_count=1
```

And there is a stdlib tool just for that : [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) !

```py
@lru_cache(maxsize=10)  # maxsize is optional, but better be careful if you have large data files
def pd_read_excel(filename):  # fake for demo
    global read_excel_count
    read_excel_count += 1
    print(f"call pd_read_excel, {filename=!r}, {read_excel_count=}")

def assign_to_new_grid(p):
    old_grid_values_pd = pd_read_excel('data.xlsx')
    # ...

for i in range(100):
    assign_to_new_grid(...)
```

WHich also get the `pd_read_excel` function to only be called once, the first time when the cache is not yet filled.
And it will work if you have several files too.

This is a simple "trick" that may get you a big speed boost, I know it sometimes did for me. But without a proper way to understand/reproduce your problem, I fear it will not be practical for us to search a solution to your problem.

Comment: Whoa, that's neat! I'll try it soon.